# Is correlation in electronic structure theory ‘a bin’ that accounts for all the behaviour that we do not understand?

Tags: electromagnetism, condensed-matter, quantum-electrodynamics, density-functional-theory

I have been trying to learn about exchange and correlation. I have a vague understanding of exchange. It is a repulsion due to equal direction spins, that Hartree-Fock captures exactly.

But what about correlation? I heard today that in DFT, correlation is even supposed to account for the kinetic energy that is lost when we take the kinetic energy to be the contribution from the Kohn-Shan orbitals. Makes me wonder if correlation is largely a label we put on the bit of the energy that contains everything that is poorly understood or difficult to account for. The name reinforces that view. Is this picture right? Please keep it as simple as possible.

Comment: Again, 8 months is a long time with no answer, why not copy and paste into https://materials.stackexchange.com ?